# AMD socket AM2+ CPU in an AM2 socket motherboard?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, processor-socket, am2+

Is there a way that I can determine whether an AMD socket AM2+ CPU such as the Phenom X4 will work in a motherboard with an AM2 socket?  I have an old box with an AM2 socket motherboard that I'd like to upgrade to as fast of a CPU as possible and the quad-core AMD Phenom X4 processors sound appealing if they will work in an AM2 socket.  In case it matters, these are the specs on my motherboard:

[PC Chips motherboard specs](http://www.pcchips.com.tw/PCCWebSite/Products/ProductsDetail.aspx?detailid=392&CategoryID=1&DetailName=Specification&MenuID=46&LanID=0)

Comment: Very doubtful that will support any Phenom processors... In my experience ASUS was the only company that fully supported am2+ in their am2 boards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On many motherboards, **yes**, the processor will work, but the HyperTransport speed and other specifications will be limited to that of the AM2 socket.  See the [Wikipedia article on Socket AM2+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_AM2%2B) for more information.  Make sure that the processor and system are properly cooled; this type of processor can run very hot.

Comment: Yes, if you are upgrading from a dual or single to a quad, new cooling is a MUST. Although most processors do come with some cooling now, so if you buy the X4 it should have it